# Symfony3 Related Entity not mapped back to parent on creation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, cascade, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have 2 entities `Client` and `Address` with a `OneToMany` relationship.
When I create a new client with an address, it saves both the client and address but does not set the `client_id` on the address, it is `NULL`.

I am using `fosrestbundle` and `jmsserializer` and sending the data as a json object.

In my controller I have the following:

```
/**
 * @REST\POST("/clients", name="create_client")
 */
public function createClientAction(Request $request)
{
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $client = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), 'AppBundle\Entity\Client', 'json');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($client);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->view($client, 200);
}
```

Here is a simplified request payload:

```
{ "name" : "foo", "addresses" : [ { "zip" : "12345" } ]
```

In my database it creates a new `client` with `name = foo` along with an `address` with `zip = 12345`, however the field `client_id` is `NULL`

My entities are mapped as follows:

```
//Client.php
...
...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */ 
private $addresses;

//Address.php
...
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="addresses")
 *
 */
private $client;
```

## update

I'm even more confused now, I just realized I do not have any getters/setters in my entities, yet I am able to get / set data.

I am guessing `setting` has something to do with `serializer->deserialize`. I have the following in my services:

```
jms_serializer.object_constructor:
    alias: jms_serializer.doctrine_object_constructor
    public: false
```

And `getting` has something to do with the fosrestbundle. Here is the get route:

```
/**
 * @REST\GET("/clients/{client}", name="get_client")
 */
public function getClientAction(Request $request, Client $client)
{
    return $this->view($client, 200);
}
```

Comment: $address->setClient($client) is not being called.  Adjust Client::addAddress accordingly.

Comment: So basically add `$address->setClient($this);` to `Client::addAddress`? I tried that and it didn't seem to have any effect. On a side note, I noticed I did not create getters or setters for my address, yet it still appears to be getting/setting the data. So I went in and deleted the getters/setters for client and cleared my cache. I am still able to do crud operations on my entities. I'm not sure why it doesn't need the getters/setters??? I'm guessing its part of the jms_serializer / fosrestbundle. Any thoughts?

Comment: The magic of reflection.  Doctrine operates directly on the instance data.  Not sure about the serializer but looks like it does the same thing.

Comment: OneToMany relations: you'll have to set both sides of your relationship, just setting and persisting one side is not always enough, check the doc here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I needed to `merge` and not `persist` the entity.

I updated the route:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->merge($client);
$em->flush();
```

and the `Client` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
 */ 
private $addresses;
```

Seems to be working now!